# Find all pair combinations with R

Tags: r

I need some help finding all pair values in a data frame. I know about aggregate and count functions, but I'm a little hung up because I have a variable amount of attributes in a column..

Sample data:

```
           dfs.V2
1          51,26,48
2                51
3                32
4                26
5             92,26
6                94
7                94
8                24
9                26
10            48,51
11               32
12               32
13           25,126
14               32
15            25,24
16               32
17            92,48
18               32
19           118,48
20               32
21               32
22               32
23            51,94
24               26
25               48
26               32
27               48
28               32
29            51,48
30               32
31        50,118,92
32               32
33   24,48,26,51,92
34               32
35               32
36               26
37      25,24,48,50
38               32
39               26
40               32
41  114,24,25,51,92
42  50,51,24,48,118


The example output 
51,26: [count]
51,48: [count]
26,48: [count]

enter code here
```

and so on.

Ordering matters, example a pair of 51,26 and 26,51 should count as two of the same pair combination, not individually one count.

And no, it's not homework, just a side project that I'm working on using real world data related to my job to teach myself R in my spare time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want pairs to be determined based on numbers in the same row. e.g. 51,26,48 gets one count each for the pairs {26,51} {26,48} and {48,51}

```
v2 <- c('51,26,48', '51', '32', '26', '92,26', '94', '94', '24', '26', '48,51', '32', '32', '25,126', '32', '25,24', '32', '92,48', '32', '118,48', '32', '32', '32', '51,94', '26', '48', '32', '48', '32', '51,48', '32', '50,118,92', '32', '24,48,26,51,92', '32', '32', '26', '25,24,48,50', '32', '26', '32', '114,24,25,51,92', '50,51,24,48,118')

v2 <- strsplit(v2, split = ',')

comb <- lapply(v2, function(x) if (length(x) > 1) combn(sort(as.numeric(x)), 2))
comb <- do.call(cbind, comb)

result <- as.data.frame(table(paste(comb[1,], comb[2,], sep = ',')))
head(result)
#     Var1 Freq
# 1 24,114    1
# 2 24,118    1
# 3  24,25    3
# 4  24,26    1
# 5  24,48    3
# 6  24,50    2
```